# awk, 4th column everything matching wildcard before the @

Tags: awk

I am trying to pull data from a pmta mail log.

a single entry look as follows

```
b,2013-02-04 03:48:57+0200,2013-02-04 03:48:57+0200,noreply@test.com,fynnb@domain.com,rfc822;fynnb@domain.com,failed,5.3.2 (system not accepting network messages),smtp;550 Too many invalid recipients,mx02.domain.com (146.230.128.12),other,smtp,twww01.test.com(10.0.0.53),,143.37.222.256,146.230.128.12,,,virtmail23,,,domain.com/virtmail23,test-promo,,,,,,,,,,,
```

There are many entries and i would just like to pull out entries that have "*@test.com" after the 3rd comma

currently noreply@test.com is in the example, but we use noreply, NoReply, No-Reply and user, so i would like to use a wildcard before the @ symbol.

what I have so far is

```
awk -F, '$4 == "noreply@test.com"' /home/mail/test.csv
```

which works well to pull out entries containing "noreply@test.com" but if I use

```
awk -F, '$4 == "*@test.com"' /home/mail/test.csv
```

I get no data. 
What can I use for * in awk in this senario?

Comment: "\*" means "zero or more repetitions of the preceeding RE sub-group" when used after something in an RE, but when used at the start of an RE it means the literal "\*" character. You probably meant ".\*@test.com" (where ".\*" means zero or more repetitions of any character) but if you think about it, that's identical to "@test.com".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell awk to do an RE comparison (~) instead of a string comparison (==):

```
awk -F, '$4 ~ /@test\.com/' /home/mail/test.csv
```